# Redirect all pages to Sign in, in RAILS 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

I've been looking for a way to redirect all requests of my app to the sign_in page if the user is not signed in, but I haven't found a way to do it (I could do it verifying a system variable and then redirect_to, but it does sound like the bad way)

I'm using ldap_authenticatable (devise) to authenticate, and then use Cancancan (for Access Control List), is there a way to use those tools (Cancancan) to do this ? , or how should I do it?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add `before_filter :authenticate_user!` to your base `ApplicationController`. [Devise Docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers)

Answer (score 2):

Devise uses "authenticate_user!" filter to authenticate users. For authenticating users you can do something like this:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

It will trigger authentication for all methods and if you want authentication only for some specific actions then you can use only or except options like:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [your actions].
```

For more detail [click here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Answer (score 1):

add

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
       before_action :authenticate_user!
 end
```

in the **application controller**, this will automatically authenticate the user, if he is not logged in then he will be redirected to the sign_in page automatically